# Ignition coil circuit creates several hundred volts on metal case

Tags: coil, arc

I designed and built this simple ignition coil arc generator a while ago but I've never fully understood one of its properties.[image]

[image]

It's just a 555 driving a MOSFET with some resonant capacitors across the primary to increase the duration of the primary pulse by making it oscillate back and forth. When I first built this I had the power button (R5) hot glued to the black metal body of the ignition coil. However, with this setup I would always get a small shock when I pressed the button with my thumb. I tried moving the button onto the battery like how it is in the photo but I was still getting shocked. I was only able to stop this by wrapping the button and wires from the button in electrical tape.

But I really want to know how this happens. The metal body of the ignition coil is completely isolated from the coils inside it yet a voltage is still produced on it with respect to ground. This is what it looks like on the oscilloscope with the probe held how its shown in the first image:

[image]

It's almost equal to the actual primary voltage in terms of peak value and is of course the same frequency. How is this happening if the metal body is not connected to anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How is this happening if the metal body is not connected to anything?*

It can happen because of internal parasitic capacitance between the transformer windings and the metal body. It doesn't need a whole lot of capacitance between the coils and case to feel a "small shock" (as you described it).

If you have a meter capable of measuring capacitance, power down the circuit and measure the capacitance. It's also quite possible that the HT output is coupling to the case too and that would give a tingle with only a few tens of pico farad parasitic capacitance.

Comment: Wow that's very interesting. If I were to measure this capacitance it would vary along the distance of the primary coil right? So if I placed one probe in-line with half-way up the primary coil I would read the lowest capacitance for that specific point if the other probe was half way up the primary coil since the distance is the smallest? Also, how would one mitigate this issue properly? Electrical tape obviously works but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Earthing the metal body seems a good way but, is it really a problem?